# T-test "KeyError" issue with CSV file in Python statistical tests

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, testing

My code is below (taken directly from my professor with the names changed):

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind

group1 = df1['pref_foot'] == 'Right'
group2 = df1['pref_foot'] == 'Left'

print ('var1 %0.3f var2 %0.3f' % (df1['FIFAdata'][group1].var(), df1['FIFAdata'][group2].var()))
t, pvalue = ttest_ind(df1['FIFAdata'][group1], df1['FIFAdata'][group2], axis=0, equal_var=False)
print ('t statistic %0.3f p-value %0.3f' % (t, pvalue))
```

Above I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.read_csv('FIFAdata.csv')
df1.head()
```

When I run it, it gives me the error -  `KeyError: 'FIFAdata'`

I have checked this multiple times and can't figure out why it does not like the CSV file. All my other code with this file works correctly.

Comment: The data is from https://www.kaggle.com/stefanoleone992/fifa-19-fifa-ultimate-team/version/7   with the title of the CSV file changed

Comment: Check your `df1.columns`. You have to find *exactly* `FIFAdata` there. Check for additional whitespaces before and after the actual `FIFAdata` string.

Comment: Do you have a column named 'FIFAdata'?